# How do I make the whole floating elements-block align to center of its parent container?

Tags: html, css

In this example. The red items are all stick to the left of its yellow container. What can I do to make them stay in the middle of the parent container so that the yellow color can show up in both left and right (now only right)

```css
.item {
  background:red;
  float:left;
  width:26%
}

#container {
width:600px;
background:#ff0;
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aim of this question kind of defats the purpose of using float.

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be placed along the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it. The element is removed from the normal flow of the web page, though still remaining a part of the flow

[MDN - float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

---

Instead, you can use `display:flex` to layout the items and `justify-content: center` to center them.

```css
.item {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 1 25%;
}

#container {
  width: 600px;
  background: #ff0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
</div>
```

---

Or if you can't use flex (maybe you need to support IE9, who knows), instead use `display:inline-block` with `text-align: center`

```css
.item {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

#container {
  width: 600px;
  background: #ff0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I have to use only `float`, is there still a way?

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding:

```css
.item {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  width: 33%
}

#container {
  width: 600px;
  background: #ff0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow:auto;
  padding: 0 90px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
</div>
```